# Evaluation of successive powers of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

The problem calls for a deduction of the equation $$1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=0$$
Where $z=\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}$.

Hence $$\begin{align}z+z^2+z^3+z^4&=\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)+\left(\cos\frac{4\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{4\pi}{5}\right)+\left(\cos\frac{6\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{6\pi}{5}\right)+\left(\cos\frac{8\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{8\pi}{5}\right)\\&=\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+\cos\frac{4\pi}{5}+\cos\frac{6\pi}{5}+\cos\frac{8\pi}{5}\right)\\&+\left(\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{5}+\sin\frac{6\pi}{5}+\sin\frac{8\pi}{5}\right)i\end{align}$$

Must equal $-1$. However, I simplified (seemingly erroneously) the equation to $z+z^2+z^3+z^4=\cos 4\pi+i\sin 4\pi$, which equals $1$.

**1.** How might I have evaluated this equation?

**2.** The previous solution established that $z^5=1$. Is this of any significance in the present problem?

Comment: **Hint:** $z^5-1=(z-1)(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4)$.

Comment: Which in turn equals 0, hence $1+z^2+z^3+z^4=0$. Thank you. I had overlooked that, and overestimated the complexity of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Since $$z^5-1=(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)$$ will gives all $5$-th of unity except $1$ are roots of $$z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1.$$

Secondly, Since $z\ne 0$, if we divede $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1$ by $z^2$ we will get $$z^2+z+z+\frac1z+\frac1{z^2}.$$ Say $u=z+\frac1z$ then $$u^2=z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}+2.$$ Hence we will get $$z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=u^2+u-1$$ which is a quadratic equation. We can find the roots and then using $u=z+\frac1z$ we will solve another quadratic equations, which are simple.